# Get the last three values of column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to create a report that pulls the **last 3 cell values** in a column.

This will need to be in three **separate** cells.

**Column C** will contain data which will be added to daily.

- **D2** will contain the value of the **last but 2 cell in column C**.
- **D3** will contain the value of the **last but 1 cell in column C**.
- **D4** will contain the value of the **last cell in column C**.

Note : I'm using **Google Sheets**.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome. Did you see this answer (`=INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A),1)`) by @EricSmalling in StackOverflow [Get the last non-empty cell in a column in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43141556/1330560). You can apply this to your scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

`=QUERY(SORTN(FILTER({C:C,ROW(C:C)},C:C<>""),3,0,2,0),"Select Col1 ORDER BY Col2")`

`FILTER` creates a virtual array containing all non-blank data from C:C alongside the row number for each row.

`SORTN` returns three results, discounting for ties (which won't exist since each row number is unique), from the virtual array after sorting it upside-down by row number.

`QUERY` reorders in the original row order and then returns just the three results in the data column (i.e., excludes the no-longer-needed row numbers).